# Uncaught TypeError (jQuery) - setting readonly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I have a bootstrap-switch set up, I just want to set one of the items to read only.

I have tried:

```
$('#charge').bootstrapSwitch('setReadOnly', true);
```

But I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

The HTML is:

```
<input name="name1" type="checkbox" class="item-types"
       id="charge"
       data-size="large"
       data-indeterminate="true"
       data-on-text="YES"
       data-off-text="NO" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of bootstrapswitch are you using? V3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may have the first parameter wrong. Should be

```
$('#charge').bootstrapSwitch('readonly', true);
```

http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/options.html